# Elastic Search - Prioritize Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have three indices: cities, museums and sights.

Now I am querying on all indices (`_all`) for a term, for example "Vienna"

```
'query' :{
    'fuzzy' : {
        'name': 'vienna'
    }
}
```

and as results I get:

1. Vienna: Vienna Art Museum `(Museum)`
2. Vienna: Vienna History Museum `(Museum)`
3. Vienna's Riesenrad `(Sight)`
4. Vienna `(cities)`

Is there a way to prioritize the indices, so that I get first cities, than sights and last the museums, something like this:

1. Vienna `(cities)`
2. Vienna's Riesenrad `(Sight)`
3. Vienna: Vienna Art Museum `(Museum)`
4. Vienna: Vienna History Museum `(Museum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, by adding a boost for each index in the desired order:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "name": "vienna"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": {
              "value": "cities",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": {
              "value": "sights",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": {
              "value": "museums",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this might not always work.

Documents are scored based on partially on term frequency (notice how the docs with `Vienna` in them twice came first). This could cause records from `sights` or `museums`  to still come first.

Furthermore, the score from the term queries above will be affected by the number of docs in each index.

If, for example, there are _lots_ of documents in the cities index, and only a few in sights and museum, it's possible that a match on the latter two indexes could result in a high enough score that results come out of order.

Comment: @orangejulius Yes, of course, however without more information on data, shard count, etc, this is good enough for what the OP is asking. If he encounters further issues, he'll feel free to create a new question with more detailed information ;-)